# Undertake followed by a gerund or infinitive?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Do they mean the same or different?

**

> 1 We might undertake going forward. 2 We might undertake to go forward.

**
Additional info.

Dictionaries say that: 1 **undertake + a noun** *means* to do or begin to do something, especially something that will take a long time or be difficult 2 **undertake to infinitive** *means* to promise to do

So, the meanings must be different.

Comment: They mean the same, but (2) is much more natural. We usually speak of undertaking a task rather than an action.

Comment: I have added elaboration,

Comment: I don't consider that there is a hard and fast distinction. [This](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undertake) definition gives examples with a noun for both senses.

Comment: So, how do you interpret the original ones? 1 They promised to go forward. OR 2 They tried/started going forward.

Comment: I understood them to mean "We might try going forward". It seems a more likely interpretation than "We might promise to..."

Comment: One big point of potential confusion: The phrase "going forward" has an idiomatic ([perhaps cliched and abused](https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2011/aug/30/mind-your-language-going-forward)) meaning of "in the future." It's easy, especially without context, to misread the first example as a sentence fragment: "We might undertake, going forward, to take on more work."

Comment: Also, unless you're talking about actual physical movement ("We can't go forward! There's an elephant in the way!"), it might be nice to use a more direct word, like "We might try to **continue**," or "to **progress**" or **make progress**.

Answer (score 2):

The full Oxford English Dictionary includes these two definitions...

> **undertake**
> **4a** - *To take upon oneself; to take in hand.*
> Sometimes contextually *‘to enter upon, **begin**’.*

> **4c** - *To give a formal **promise** or pledge that; to take upon oneself to promise or affirm; to venture to assert.*

(where definitions 1-3 are all marked "obsolete"). Clearly there's a difference between actually *beginning* to do something, and simply *promising* to do it. But contextually it's usually obvious which sense is intended. Note that *in between* those two definitions, the OED has...

> **4b**  Const. **to with infinitive**. (Sometimes implying a solemn pledge or promise: **cf. next**.)

...which has no associated *explicit* definition. Contextually you might therefore reasonably suppose **4b** is "the same" definition as **4a** (the only difference being the syntax of usage with an **infinitive** rather than **noun**). But *semantically* I attach significance to highlighted **cf next** in the above (implying that the syntax of **4b** is *particularly* relevant to sense **4c**).

---

Both of OP's examples are syntactically valid, but because ***to go forward*** pretty much means ***to start, to begin***, there might be some disagreement as to exactly what either or both actually mean. My own off-the-cuff interpretation, with no further context, would be...

> *We might undertake **going** forward*
> = *We may **try** or **adopt** the strategy of going forward*
> (as opposed to going backward or sideways?!)

> *We might undertake **to go** forward*
> = *We may **publicly commit ourselves** to the strategy of going forward*